# define color in Xamarin.Forms XAML without "The type 'Color' does not support direct content"

Tags: xaml, xamarin.forms

There are a number of places in the Xamarin docs and blog ([here's one](https://blog.xamarin.com/easy-app-theming-with-xamarin-forms-styles/), and the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/colors) don't even cover this issue) that refer to color definitions in a `ResourceDictionary` that look like this:

```
<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <Color x:Key="backgroundColor">#33302E</Color>
        <Color x:Key="textColor">White</Color>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```

That seems to be old news, however, because if you try that now, you get a compilation error -- **`The type 'Color' does not support direct content`**.

The current norm seems to be to use a `FactoryMethod` (like `FromHsla`) and pass numeric color arguments. But is there a current concise syntax for defining `Color` keys (by name, ideally, like `Red`) in a `ResourceDictionary`, using XAML?

Comment: The way you're doing it should [work perfectly well](https://imgur.com/1slMU1o). Make sure you're referencing all necessary `xmlns` namespaces.

Comment: It demonstrably does *not* work in Xamarin.Forms 3.4 (latest), your jpeg notwithstanding. The only namespace that's referenced is xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" -- what else are you suggesting is required? I tried referencing System.Color, but the same compilation error comes up -- does not support direct content.

Comment: Are you missing the `http://` in your namespace ?

Comment: No. Here's the entire definition: `<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:assets="clr-namespace:MyApp.Assets"
             x:Class="MyApp.Assets.Colors">`  It's not my references -- the syntax simply doesn't work anymore in 3.4. If <Color>Red</Color> still works for you, you're either using an older X.F or some other Color library.

Comment: It works with both, 3.1 and 3.4.0.1008975. Sometimes VS gets a little cranky when it comes to XAML. One thing you can try is to tell it exactly where to find `Color` : `xmlns:xyz="clr-namespace:Xamarin.Forms;assembly=Xamarin.Forms.Core"` and then use `<xyz:Color/>`. Of course, adjust it for whatever prefix you like.

Comment: Still doesn't work. `<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="MyApp.Assets.Colors"
             xmlns:xyz="clr-namespace:Xamarin.Forms;assembly=Xamarin.Forms.Core">

    <xyz:Color x:Key="Test">Blue</xyz:Color>

</ResourceDictionary>` still returns with "The type 'Color' does not support direct content.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have the same issue, My workaround in Xaml is like so:

```
    <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="Color" x:Key="TextColor">
        <On Platform="iOS, Android" Value="#000000" />
    </OnPlatform>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you define a color via `ResourceDictionary` you only can declare it by Hex (with or without alpha channel), the enum color actually is defined via code on the [Color class](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/blob/bd31e1e9fc8b2f9ad94cc99e0c7ab058174821f3/Xamarin.Forms.Core/Color.cs#L412), you can create a color list this way

```
namespace YourNamespace
{
    public static class Colors
    {
        public statis Color BackgroundColor = Color.FromHex("#33302E");

        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, I'm aware that I can use C# to declare the color constants -- `public static Color ReverseTextBackground = Color.DarkGray;` -- but the question is how to use XAML, as the documentation appears to be incorrect.